# Having problems with Java and GUI

Tags: java

Having a problem getting my code to work correctly. I can't get the char array (myArray) to display in the GUI. When it works correctly I have to display the array, if the letters are used next I have to re-display the array with the letters used gone.  Continue this until the array of letters is empty.I placed in quotes what the instructions for the assignment. I am currently working with Eclipse.

> Develop the Game – based on “Wordmole”
>   Show the user a grid of letters (read
>   from a file). Let the user enter a
>   word using an input dialog. If the
>   word that was entered is valid, then
>   check if all the letters of the word
>   appear in the grid. else use a message
>   dialog to display an error message. If
>   all the letters of the word are in the
>   grid, then award the player the
>   appropriate points for the word, and
>   delete the letters from the gird. else
>   use a message dialog to tell the user
>   the word is not there. Let the player
>   continue playing until The user quits
>   the game by not entering a word or by
>   clicking on cancel. The grid has no
>   more letters in it.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
//import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Project2 {
    public static String inputWord;
    public static String matrix = "Words\n\n";
    public static String total = "Total\n\n";
    public static String newWord;
    public static char[][] myArray; 

public static void main(String[] args){ 

    myArray = fillArray("project2a.txt");


    while(true){
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        inputWord = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a word:");
        if(inputWord == null || inputWord.length() == 0) break;
        newWord = inputWord.toUpperCase();

        if(IsValidWord(newWord)){
            for(int x = 0; x < newWord.length(); x++){

                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                        if(newWord.charAt(x) == myArray[i][j]) count++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(count == newWord.length()){
                for(int c = 0; c < newWord.length(); c++)
                    sum += scoreValue(newWord.charAt(c)); 

                for(int x = 0; x < newWord.length(); x++){

                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                            if(newWord.charAt(x) == myArray[i][j]) myArray[i][j] = (' ');
                        }
                    }   
                }
                matrix = matrix + newWord + "\n";
                total = total + sum + "\n";
            }
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The word is not there!!!");




            } // IF

        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR: The word is invalid!!!");

        } //while
    createAndShowGUI();
}

public static char[][] fillArray(String myFile){
    TextFileInput tfi = new TextFileInput(myFile);
    String line = tfi.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    int rows, cols;
    rows = Integer.parseInt(line);
    cols = Integer.parseInt(line);

    char[][] rtn = new char[rows][cols];

    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        line = tfi.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        for(int j= 0; j < cols; j++) {
            rtn[i][j] = line.charAt(j);

        } // For
    } // For
    return rtn;
} // FillArray

public static boolean IsValidWord(String myWord){
    for(int i = 0; i < myWord.length(); i++)
        if(!Character.isLetter(myWord.charAt(i))) return false;
    return true;
} // IsValidWord

public static int scoreValue(char letters){
    if(Character.isLetter(letters)){
        if(letters == 'A' || letters == 'E' || letters == 'I' || letters == 'O' || letters == 'U') 
            return 0;
        else if(letters == 'K' || letters == 'V' || letters == 'F' || letters == 'W') return 5;
        else if(letters == 'X' || letters == 'Q') return 10;
        } // If statement
    return 1;

    } // scoreValue

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Word Game");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize( 100,100);//width, height);
    frame.setLocation(200,200);//x, y);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea1.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(textArea1);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane2);

    textArea.setText(matrix);
    textArea1.setText(total);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


}// createAndShowGUI

public static void createAndShowGUI2() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Letters");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize( 100,100);//width, height);
    frame.setLocation(200,200);//x, y);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    textArea.setText(myArray);


    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);


}// createAndShowGUI
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you removed all of the code but the part you are having trouble with.  We don't need to see your logic for the game.

Comment: In the future, try to implement the pieces of your code independently (and incrementally) and test each piece before putting the pieces together.  The difficulty of debugging a program grows exponentially the more code you write before testing it.

Answer (score 1):

JTextComponent setText gets a String while you are passing a multidimensional char array. I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but try to come up with an approach to turn into a string before displaying. Remember String class has a constructor that accepts a char array ;)

Comment: Would the best approach be use copyValueOf?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so your trying to initialise a textArea with an array, if you look at the api for JTextArea it has a method setText(String someText) which will not work if you pass in an array. I'm surprised that eclipse hasn't flagged this up as error for you. So you will need to loop around your character array and set the fields using insert(string, position) see the api. Couple this with shendrics answer of creating a string from a char array and you should be set to go.

[JTextArea Api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)